# Images not loaded on first call in html canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to load the sorted array images in canvas in a same sequence, for that i created a load function and I am calling it from there.

Every thing works fine, but the problem is that it does not draw the images on canvas at first call.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohib/wdfrrayh/1/)

With my current code, it does not show you an image , but when you run it again, it will create and show the canvas image.

I am facing the same issue in my local host where i load the images with ajax.

```js
var ImagesArray = new Array("http://s4.postimg.org/dw8aujkkd/slim_Fit.png",
  "http://s27.postimg.org/l6mq3hboz/outer_collar1.png",
  "http://s22.postimg.org/e7alkm44x/inner_collar11.png",
  "http://s12.postimg.org/h4kgdjn4t/maincolar.png",
  "http://s13.postimg.org/edabwknfr/outer_fastening1.png");

//alert(ImagesArray.length);
MainMethods(ImagesArray);



function MainMethods(responseImages) {
  //alert(responseImages.length);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("product-image");

  canvas.height = ($(window).height()) - 120;
  canvas.width = canvas.height * 0.75;
  var heightscreen = ($(window).height()) - 120;
  var canvasheight = heightscreen;
  var canvaswidth = canvas.height * 0.75;
  canvaswidthdiv4 = 0;
  var widthNeeded = canvasheight * 0.75;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


  var returnedImages = loadImages(responseImages);


  for (i = 0; i < returnedImages.length; i++) {
    console.log(returnedImages[i]);
    context.drawImage(returnedImages[i], canvaswidthdiv4, 55, widthNeeded, canvasheight);
  }



  // Image loading global variables
  var loadcount = 0;
  var loadtotal = 0;
  var preloaded = false;

  // Load images
  function loadImages(imagefiles) {
    // Initialize variables
    loadcount = 0;
    loadtotal = imagefiles.length;
    preloaded = false;

    // Load the images
    var loadedimages = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < imagefiles.length; i++) {
      // Create the image object
      var image = new Image();

      // Add onload event handler
      image.onload = function() {
        loadcount++;
        if (loadcount == loadtotal) {
          // Done loading
          preloaded = true;
        }
      };

      // Set the source url of the image
      image.src = imagefiles[i];

      // Save to the image array
      loadedimages[i] = image;
    }

    // Return an array of images
    return loadedimages;
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="product-image" width="700" height="823"></canvas>
```

Comment: cant open the fiddle... nvm, silly mistake

Comment: @Shocklo yup it is http://jsfiddle.net/mohib/wdfrrayh/1/

Comment: @MohibSalahuddin When the editor alerts you that you must place the code in the question, that doesn't mean a link to the code, but the actual code; questions on SO should be self-containted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your images are not loaded yet when you try to draw it.

Wrap the `drawImage` part in a function and call it when preloaded becomes true, here your boolean does nothing.

I refactored your code a little bit, you also had an issue with `loadtotal` being reset to 0 after your call to `loadImage()` function. So `loadcount`won't ever be === `loadtotal` and your useless preloaded never switched to true.

```js
var ImagesArray = new Array ("http://s4.postimg.org/dw8aujkkd/slim_Fit.png",
                   "http://s27.postimg.org/l6mq3hboz/outer_collar1.png",
                   "http://s22.postimg.org/e7alkm44x/inner_collar11.png",
                   "http://s12.postimg.org/h4kgdjn4t/maincolar.png",
                   "http://s13.postimg.org/edabwknfr/outer_fastening1.png");

function MainMethods(responseImages) {

 var canvas = document.getElementById("product-image");

 canvas.height = ($(window).height()) - 120;
 canvas.width = canvas.height * 0.75;
 var canvasheight = ($(window).height()) - 120;
 var canvaswidth = canvas.height * 0.75;
 canvaswidthdiv4 = 0;
 var widthNeeded = canvasheight * 0.75;
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');



 // an other error, if you set loadtotal to 0 after calling loadImages(), it will be set to 0 when images are loaded.
 // and loadcount won't ever be === loadtotal.
 var loadcount;
 var loadtotal;

 function loadImages(imagefiles) {
  loadcount = 0;
  loadtotal = imagefiles.length;

  var loadedimages = [];
  for (var i=0; i<imagefiles.length; i++) {
   var image = new Image();
 
   image.onload = function () {
    loadcount++;
    console.log(loadcount+'/'+ loadtotal);
    if (loadcount == loadtotal) {
                  // done loading all the images
     draw(loadedimages);
    }
   };
                
   image.src = imagefiles[i];

   loadedimages[i] = image;
  }
 
 }

 // Wrap your drawing in a function that will be called asynchronously
 function draw(loadedimages){
  for (var i = 0; i < loadedimages.length; i++) { 
   console.log(loadedimages[i]);
   context.drawImage(loadedimages[i], canvaswidthdiv4, 55, widthNeeded, canvasheight);
   }
  }

 // Once all your variables are set, you can load the images
 loadImages(responseImages);
}

MainMethods(ImagesArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="product-image"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears to be a browser specific issue, here's a hack to get it to work:

Replace :  `MainMethods(ImagesArray);`

with : `setTimeout(function () { MainMethods(ImagesArray); }, 0);`

With timeout set to 0 ms, it would virtually execute instantaneously.

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wdfrrayh/3/

Tested on IE, FF, Chrome

Comment: when you try it on new tab you will see it will not work, actually it shows only when it stores in cache.

Comment: It works on Firefox and chrome. I guess your issue is related to IE then.

Comment: i was on chrome; however i tried it on firefox but it keeps the same :( actually it only shows when it stored in cache, it looks may be load delay time effecting on it?

Comment: actually its amazing that it does not work on any of the 3 browser when i do hard refresh, all those works fine when i do only refresh as they retrieve it from cache, but after clearing cache it does not;

so when i press run again, it works

i tried i wrap all that in CallAgain function & call that function twice but it does not help either

here i updated http://jsfiddle.net/mohib/wdfrrayh/8/

Comment: @MohibSalahuddin: Sorry but i didn't get what you meant by saying "hard refresh".

Comment: i mean when i do "ctrl+F5" or when i clear cache and try, as a first visit on the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88638/discussion-between-mohib-salahuddin-and-dinomyte).

Answer (score 0):

image src needs to be called after drawImage which i was doing before I have updated my function which is working fine,

below is working code for this

```
function loadImages(sources, callback, jsondata) {

    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById('product-image');

    canvas.height = (jQuery(window).height()) -120;
      canvas.width = canvas.height * 0.75;
  var heightscreen = (jQuery(window).height()) -120;
  var canvasheight = heightscreen;
  var canvaswidth = canvas.height * 0.75;
  canvaswidthdiv4 = 0;
  var widthNeeded = canvasheight * 0.75;

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  


 var sources = new Array ("http://s4.postimg.org/dw8aujkkd/slim_Fit.png",
               "http://s27.postimg.org/l6mq3hboz/outer_collar1.png",
               "http://s22.postimg.org/e7alkm44x/inner_collar11.png",
               "http://s12.postimg.org/h4kgdjn4t/maincolar.png",
               "http://s13.postimg.org/edabwknfr/outer_fastening1.png");


      loadImages(sources, function(images) {

          for(var i=0; i < sources.length; i++){
             context.drawImage(images[i], canvaswidthdiv4, 55,widthNeeded,canvasheight); 
          }


      });
```